# Restore the ProfileInfo web part in person.aspx

Tags: 2013, my-site, mysites

I deleted the Profile Info Viewer web part on the person.aspx mysite, thinking I could re-add it in a different web part zone on the page later, but I can't find that web part to add back onto my page again. Can someone please tell me how to get that web part back on my person.aspx page?

Comment: Did you ever found out the solution to this, i am in the same situation now. I'd be grateful if you could share the solution.

Answer (score -1):

For others who land at this page - you need to populate the webpart into the webpart gallery.

Comment: Can you please add details regarding how to do what you propose?